# Conversion of Google Map webpart into Bing Map webpart

Tags: c#, sharepoint, google-maps, web-parts, bing-maps

here is the Google [version](http://sp2010googlemaps.codeplex.com/)

I did almost 2 days research to find something like this for **Bing Maps**, but no luck, Now I am looking to change this Google Map project into Bing Map project, I have no Clue.

Can someone Explain the code of this project and the changes I need to make it Pick up Bing Maps.

I know I need to Change `GoogleMap.js` to `BingMap.js`, I can get this script from Bing [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/), but i can't figure out what else changes i will have to make.

Here is the Bing Map Project, but its getting Image of Map and not actually using [Maps API](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/)

Comment: Where all experts gone ? , I am trying to get solution of this problem since last week, but seems like no one here really have knowledge about Maps API !

Comment: Your question could be shortened to "I have seen something cool I cannot reproduce will someone please do it." I think you should try to cast it as something a little more specific and probably also less as a conversion problem to persuade someone that it will be worthwhile the effort to analyse a codeplex project on your behalf.

Comment: I do have knowledge about maps, but here you're asking us to do your job. Post a specific question that shows you've tried something to get a chance of having an answer.

Comment: @ You Guys are right, I am going to do more research on it now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find what I wanted, and here is the Link,

[enter link description here](http://virtualearthwebpart.codeplex.com/)

and thanks People for your Negative Comments !

One thing I would like to mention that, I went through Apress Book "Sharepoint 2010 as development platform" which shows you how to deploy a bing map as webpart but they missed the most Important bit, In there Code (got from there website) they are not registering the script using "ClientScriptManager" which is breaking javascript and when you use that webpart it doesn't let you use the ribbon Controls, So if anyone had issues (as i seen many posts people having same problem) Just add the following before your java script (for sharepoint 2010 webparts)

```
 System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager csm = Page.ClientScript;
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 string SCRIPT_NAME = "MapScript" + this.ID;
    {// your java script}
csm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), SCRIPT_NAME, builder.ToString(), false);
```

If I said anything wrong please correct me, Cheers (and if my answer helped you rate it :))